# BIG O time complexity of TSP algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, traveling-salesman

I've written 2 nearest neighbor algorithms in python and I have to analyize the runtime complexity by O(n) and Θ(n).
So I've tried several samples and I don't understand why one of my algorithm is faster than the other one.

So here is my Code for the repeated nearest neighbor (RNN) algorithm:

```
def repeated_nn_tsp(cities):
   return shortest_tour(nn_tsp(cities, start) for start in cities)

def shortest_tour(self, tours):
 return min(tours, key=self.tour_length)
```

nn_tsp has a runtime complexity of O(n^2) and every startpoint will create a new NN Tour. Through all NN tours I have to find the best tour.
That's why I think the time complexity of the RNN has to be T(n)=O(n^3) and T(n)=Θ(n^3).

So here is my Code for the altered nearest neighbor (ANN) algorithm:

```
def alter_tour(tour):
    original_length = tour_length(tour)
    for (start, end) in all_segments(len(tour)):
        reverse_segment_if_better(tour, start, end)
    if tour_length(tour) < original_length:
        return alter_tour(tour)
    return tour

def all_segments(N):
    return [(start, start + length) for length in range(N, 2-1, -1) for start in range(N - length + 1)]

def reverse_segment_if_better(tour, i, j):
    A, B, C, D = tour[i-1], tour[i], tour[j-1], tour[j % len(tour)]
    if distance(A, B) + distance(C, D) > distance(A, C) + distance(B, D):
        tour[i:j] = reversed(tour[i:j])
```

The time complexity of all_segments should be T(n) = O(1/2 * n^2 - 0.5n) -> O(n^2) and creates n^2 elements.
Inside the Loop through all_segments (through n^2 elements) I call the function reverse_segment_if_better. I'll use the reversed method of python, which causes a time complexity of O(n).
That's why I think the time complexity of the loop has to be O(n^3). When there's a better tour, the function will call itself recursive. I think the outcome of the altered NN has a time complexity of O(n^4). Is that right?

But here we come to my problem:  My evaluation, which runs the code 100times over 100cities, shows me that ANN is faster than RNN on average which is the opposite of the runtime complexity I expected. (RNN needs 4.829secs and ANN only needs 0.877secs for 1x 100-city.)

So where did I make a mistake?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May I suggest using the Cprofiler to get the counts of the function calls and the timings.

Answer (score 0):

First I must say that time-complexity and big-o notations are not always on point, one algorithm may have a 'better' running-time function but still would run slower than expected, or slower than another function with a worst running-time function, in your case, it is very hard to determine what is the worst case to feed the algorithm, and we cannot assure you have done that! Maybe the cases were 'pleasant' with the `ANN` algorithm while the other one got stuck somewhere..? this is why it is not always 100% correct to rely only on the running time function we calculate.

What I am trying to say, is that you most probably did not make a mistake in your calculations on purpose, because they are hard functions to analyze on the fly, or [What kind of input would be the worst, for example](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249056/what-is-known-about-worst-case-point-sets-for-the-travelling-salesman-problem)

---

### As for the 'why?':

1. When talking about actual personal running time (as you gave an example of 0.877seconds), it boils down to our own machines, each computer has its own running hardware behind the curtains, not all computers are born the same.
2. Secondly, when we talk about running time complexity, we drop the low term values as you did with the `all_segments` function, you can see that you even dropped a negative term which in theory would help us reduce the numbers of 'operations'.
3. There are many cases in which there is a bit of code not-so efficient, that we  bother to execute only if a specific criteria is met, thus reducing the running time.
4. Last and most importantly is the fact that when we talk about classifying
   algorithms into sets such as `O(n)` or `O(nlogn)` we are talking about
   asymptotic functions, we need to look at the bigger picture and see
   what happens when we feed the algorithm very large amount of data,
   which I assume you didn't check, because as you wrote, you ran only 100 cities. That *may*
   vary if we would look at let's say, millions and millions of cities.

---

For your code, I can notice multiple parts that would reasonably be the cause of this 'weird' difference in the running time. The first, is that in the`ANN` code, more specifically in the `reverse_segment_if_better` function, we are not always reversing the list, only if a certain statement is evaluated to a truthy value. We cannot be sure what kind of input you've given the algorithm, and thus I have only to imagine it is compliant with the second algorithm.

Moreover, it may be that I am missing something (as the function `reverse_segment_if_better` / we cannot view the function `tour_length` or `distance`) but I don't see how you came up with `O(n^4)` at the end, it seems like it is doing `O(n^3)`:

`all_segments- no doubt it is O(n) - returning ~n/2 values`
The tricky part is analyzing `reverse_segment_if_better` and `alter_tour` - reversing only occurs from `i:j` thus it is not strictly correct to say it has `O(n)` - as we do not reverse the *whole* tour (at least, not for every value of `start, end`.

It is safe to say that it may be the case of not checking for very large numbers asymptotically, you gave an input and it was kind to this specific algorithm, or the final form of `T(n)` was not strict enough.